# Show relevant divs when an html select option is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

I want a div to become visible when its corresponding select option is clicked (and to hide others) unfortunately my attempts at JavaScript are terrible.

CSS

```css
#aaa, #bbb, #ccc {
    display:none;
}
```

The HTML (I use the same id name for option and div - is this incorrect?)

```
<select>
  <option>Select</option>
  <option id="aaa" value="aaa" onclick="showExtra(this)">AAA</option>
  <option id="bbb" value="bbb" onclick="showExtra(this)">BBB</option>
  <option id="ccc" value="ccc" onclick="showExtra(this)">CCC</option>
</select>

<div id="aaa">
  <p>AAA is aaamazing</p>
</div>
<div id="bbb">
  <p>BBB is bbbriliant</p>
</div>
  <div id="ccc">
<p>cccor blimey CCC</p>
</div>
```

The JavaScript

```
function showExtra(element)
{
   I don't have clue .slideToggle("medium");
}
```

Comment: IDs need to be unique. Why do you think you need IDs on the `<option>` elements?

Comment: `slideToggle` is a jQuery function. Are you using jQuery? You haven't tagged it, and other than the pseudo-comment in the code, you don't *seem* to be using it.

Comment: @ Barmar: Until/unless the OP confirms that they're using jQuery (as opposed to just having seen `slideToggle` when browsing around), it's inappropriate to add the `jquery` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the IDs in the `<option>` elements, they're not needed (or if they are, you need to rename them, e.g. `optaaa`, so they don't conflict with the IDs of the DIVs). Also, call the function from the dropdown's `onchange` event, not clicking on the options.

```
<select onchange="showExtra(this)">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="aaa">AAA</option>
  <option value="bbb">BBB</option>
  <option value="ccc">CCC</option>
</select>
```

Give all your DIVs a class, so you can operate on them as a group:

```
<div id="aaa" class="tab">
  <p>AAA is aaamazing</p>
</div>
<div id="bbb" class="tab">
  <p>BBB is bbbriliant</p>
</div>
  <div id="ccc" class="tab">
<p>cccor blimey CCC</p>
</div>
```

In the JS, you can then operate on all the DIVs that do or don't match the value.

```
function showExtra(option) {
    var divID = option.value;
    $(".tab:not(#"+divID+")").slideUp();
    $(".tab#"+divID).slideDown();
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/YF5s7/8/)